# can an excel respond to an key press event when the excel itself is not active

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro enable excel file.What I want is describing below-

1. Open the excel
2. write a application onkey event.
3. run this

untill this I have done.
the excel is responding to the keypress event.
Now I want this-

1. Minimize the excel.Thus the excel is not active.
2. Now press the key and I want the excel to respond now as well

Is it possible.
Advance thanks for you guys.Please ,I need a quick solution.Even of you have any other idea ,please share that also.

Comment: Have you tried it to see if it would work?

Answer (score 0):

[This site seems to think it's possible.](https://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=4042)  I knew the answer would be an API one, but I wasn't certain which one: `Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32" (ByVal vKey As KeyCodeConstants) As Long` would seem to be the one.